# KotlinJvmAndroidCompilation error due to upgrade Gradle from gradle 5.6.4 to gradle 5.6.1

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have faced this issue whenever I updated the Gradle from 5.4.1 to 5.6.1 following issue is generated. :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > No value has been specified for this provider.
   > KotlinJvmAndroidCompilation with name 'productionDebug' not found.

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.wrapException(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:80)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:73)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$600(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:53)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$NotifyAfterEvaluate.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject$1.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:112)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:26)

    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:58)
    ... 125 more


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

CONFIGURE FAILED in 2s
```

Using 
- kotlin version v1.3.70
- Gradle v5.6.4
- Android Studio v3.6.1

Please help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Same as me. I'm lost with this

Comment: I have solved it, my issue was because of Crashlytics plugin and  ''ext.enableCrashlytics = true" after removing it from build type debug. problem was solved

Comment: Does this answer your question? [KotlinJvmAndroidCompilation with name 'debug' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60620140/kotlinjvmandroidcompilation-with-name-debug-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue and it turned out that the cause of the issue is the fabric gradle plugin (crashlytics) rather than gradle itself.

Basically, the issue occurs when setting `ext.enableCrashlytics = true` in your `build.gradle` file using `io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.31.2` fabric plugin.

### Workaround

You have to avoid explicitly setting `ext.enableCrashlytics` to `true` (`false` is okay).

For example, you can replace the following code

```
def enableCrashlytics = // comes from somewhere
ext.enableCrashlytics = enableCrashlytics
```

by

```
def enableCrashlytics = // comes from somewhere
if (!enableCrashlytics) {
    ext.enableCrashlytics = false
}
```

The behavior remains the same since crashlytics is enabled by default.

As an alternative, you can revert to using `1.31.0` which works fine, but I'd not recommend doing it since the latest version contains a couple of critical [bug fixes](https://docs.fabric.io/android/changelog.html#fabric-gradle-plugin).

Also, you can consider migrating to Firebase Crashlytics (currently in beta) since Google is [dropping support](https://docs.fabric.io/android/examples/firebase/fabric-shutdown.html) for Fabric soon and this issue might not get fixed.

Originally answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60951508/2361725).