# KotlinJvmAndroidCompilation with name 'debug' not found

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to update my project to the last gradle, v6.2.2, but I'm facing the next error:

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Cannot query the value of this provider because it has no value available.
   > KotlinJvmAndroidCompilation with name 'debug' not found.
```

My project build.gradle is the next:

```
buildscript {

    ext.gradleToolsVersion = '3.6.1'
    ext.kotlinVersion = "1.3.70"
    ext.googleServicesVersion = "4.3.3"
    ext.butterknifeGradlePluginVersion = "10.2.0"
    ext.fabricToolsGradleVersion = "1.31.2"

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"
        classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:$googleServicesVersion" // Google Services plugin
        classpath "com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:$butterknifeGradlePluginVersion"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files

        classpath "io.fabric.tools:gradle:$fabricToolsGradleVersion"  // Crashlytics plugin

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven {
            url "http://dl.bintray.com/electronicid/maven/"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And my app build is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

// Touch Library Versions Here
ext {
    kotlinVersion = "1.3.70"
    androidxAppcompatVersion = '1.1.0'
    corektxAppcompatVersion = '1.2.0'
    fragmentktxAppcompatVersion = '1.2.2'
    androidxVersion = '1.1.0'
    multidexVersion = '2.0.1'
    preferenceVersion = '1.1.0'
    constraintLayoutVersion = '1.1.3'
    retrofitVersion = '2.7.1'
    butterknifeVersion = '10.2.1'
    okHttpVersion = '4.4.0'
    gsonVersion = '2.8.6'
    stethoVersion = '1.5.1'
    rxJavaVersion = '2.2.15'
    rxAndroidVersion = '2.1.1'
    lifecycleVersion = '2.2.0'
    kotlinCoroutineVersion = '1.3.2'
    androidSlidingUpPanelVersion = '4.0.0'
    glideVersion = '4.11.0'
    stickHeaderGridVersion = '0.9.7'
    shimmerLayout = '2.1.0'
    videoidSdkVersion = '5.2.1'
    ottoEventBusVersion = '1.3.8'
    cryptoPrefsVersion = '1.3.2.5'
    blurryVersion = '3.0.0'
    lottieVersion = '3.3.1'
    firebaseCoreVersion = '17.2.3'
    firebaseAnalyticsVersion = '17.2.3'
    firebaseMessagingVersion = '20.1.2'
    firebaseCrashVersion = '16.2.1'
    crashlyticsVersion = '2.10.1'
    circleimageviewVersion = '3.1.0'
    fotoapparatVersion = '2.7.0'
    dexterVersion = '6.0.2'
    ucropVersion = '2.2.4-native'
    commonTextVersion = '1.8'
    guavaVersion = '28.1-android'
    timberVersion = '4.7.1'
    discreteScrollViewVersion = '1.4.9'
    slideUpVersion = '2.2.8'
    biometricVersion = '1.0.1'
    playServicesLocationVersion = '17.0.0'
}

def apikeyPropertiesFile = rootProject.file("apikey.properties")
def apikeyProperties = new Properties()
apikeyProperties.load(new FileInputStream(apikeyPropertiesFile))

def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file("keystore.properties")
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))


android {

    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"

    defaultPublishConfig 'release'
    publishNonDefault true

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.planunnum"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 7084
        versionName '7.4.0'
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled = true

        // SECRET KEY TO ENCRYPT/DECRYPT SHARED PREFERENCES
        buildConfigField("String", "SHA_512_SECURE_KEY", apikeyProperties['SHA_512_SECURE_KEY'])
    }

    signingConfigs {

        release {
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['RELEASE_STORE_FILE'])
            keyAlias = keystoreProperties['RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS']
            storePassword keystoreProperties['RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD']
        }

    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            buildConfigField "boolean", "USE_CRASHLYTICS", "true"
            ext.enableCrashlytics = true
            buildConfigField "boolean", "USE_MOCKS", "false"
        }
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile(
                    'proguard-android.txt'),
                    // List additional ProGuard rules for the given build type here. By default,
                    // Android Studio creates and includes an empty rules file for you (located
                    // at the root directory of each module).
                    'proguard-rules.pro'

            signingConfig signingConfigs.release

            // enable crashlytics
            buildConfigField "boolean", "USE_CRASHLYTICS", "true"
            ext.enableCrashlytics = true
            // Disable mocks
            buildConfigField "boolean", "USE_MOCKS", "false"
        }
        mocks {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false

            buildConfigField "boolean", "USE_CRASHLYTICS", "true"
            ext.enableCrashlytics = true // Must be false, but testers are human too :(
            buildConfigField "boolean", "USE_MOCKS", "true"
        }
    }

    // Configure only for each module that uses Java 8
    // language features (either in its source code or
    // through dependencies).
    // Butterknife requires Java 8.
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    // For Kotlin projects
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }

    packagingOptions {
        // exclude ARMEABI native so file, ARMEABI has been removed in NDK r17.
        exclude "lib/armeabi/**"
    }

    // Change behaivour to rename apk deployed
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.all { output ->
            def project = "plannum"
            def SEP = "_"
            def buildType = variant.variantData.variantConfiguration.buildType.name
            def versionCode = variant.versionName
            def buildCode = variant.versionCode
            def date = new Date()
            def formattedDate = date.format('ddMMyy_HHmm')

            def newApkName = project + SEP + buildType + SEP + versionCode + SEP + buildCode + SEP + formattedDate + ".apk"

            outputFileName = new File(newApkName)
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:${kotlinVersion}"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:${kotlinVersion}"

    // BASE
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:${androidxAppcompatVersion}"
    implementation "androidx.core:core:${corektxAppcompatVersion}"
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:${corektxAppcompatVersion}"
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:${fragmentktxAppcompatVersion}"
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:${constraintLayoutVersion}"
    implementation "androidx.preference:preference-ktx:${preferenceVersion}"
    implementation "androidx.biometric:biometric:${biometricVersion}"
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:${multidexVersion}"


    // TEST
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    // BUTTERKNIFE
    implementation "com.jakewharton:butterknife:${butterknifeVersion}"
    kapt "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:${butterknifeVersion}"

    // NETWORK
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:${retrofitVersion}"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:${retrofitVersion}"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:${retrofitVersion}"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:${okHttpVersion}"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:${okHttpVersion}"
    implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:${gsonVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.stetho:stetho:${stethoVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp3:${stethoVersion}"

    // KOTLIN COROUTINES
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$kotlinCoroutineVersion"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$kotlinCoroutineVersion"

    // LIFECYCLE VIEWMODEL AND LIVEDATA
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:${lifecycleVersion}"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:${lifecycleVersion}"

    // SLIDING PANELS
    implementation "com.github.mancj:SlideUp-Android:${slideUpVersion}"
    implementation "com.yarolegovich:discrete-scrollview:${discreteScrollViewVersion}"
    implementation "com.github.hannesa2:AndroidSlidingUpPanel:${androidSlidingUpPanelVersion}"
    implementation "com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar"

    // IMAGE LOADER
    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:${glideVersion}"
    kapt "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:${glideVersion}"

    // STICY HEADERS
    implementation "com.codewaves.stickyheadergrid:stickyheadergrid:${stickHeaderGridVersion}"

    // SHIMMER LAYOUTS
    implementation "io.supercharge:shimmerlayout:${shimmerLayout}"

    // VIDEOID
    implementation "eu.electronicid.android:video-sdk:${videoidSdkVersion}"
    implementation "eu.electronicid.android:videoid-sdk:${videoidSdkVersion}"

    // OTTO EVENT BUS
    implementation "com.squareup:otto:${ottoEventBusVersion}"

    // CRYPTOPREFS TO SAVE/LOAD DATA ON SHAREDPREFERENCES
    implementation "com.github.AndreaCioccarelli:CryptoPrefs:${cryptoPrefsVersion}"


    // BLURRY LAYOUTS
    implementation "jp.wasabeef:blurry:${blurryVersion}"

    // LOTTIE FOR LOGO SPLASHSCREEN
    implementation "com.airbnb.android:lottie:${lottieVersion}"

    // FCM
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:${firebaseCoreVersion}"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:${firebaseAnalyticsVersion}"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:${firebaseMessagingVersion}"

    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:${firebaseCrashVersion}"
    implementation "com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:${crashlyticsVersion}"

    // CIRCLE IMAGE VIEWS
    implementation "de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:${circleimageviewVersion}"

    // CAPTURE PHOTOS
    implementation "io.fotoapparat:fotoapparat:${fotoapparatVersion}"

    // REACTIVE PROGRAMMING RXJAVA & RXANDROID
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:${rxJavaVersion}"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:${rxAndroidVersion}"

    // REQUEST PERMISSIONS
    implementation "com.karumi:dexter:${dexterVersion}"

    // CROPPING IMAGES
    implementation "com.github.yalantis:ucrop:${ucropVersion}"

    // COMMONS TEXT UTILS
    implementation "org.apache.commons:commons-text:${commonTextVersion}"

    // GUAVA
    implementation "com.google.guava:guava:${guavaVersion}"

    // BETTER LOG MESSAGES
    implementation "com.jakewharton.timber:timber:${timberVersion}"

    // LOCATION
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:${playServicesLocationVersion}"

    implementation project(path: ':everid-release_2.0')

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'  // Google Play services Gradle plugin
```

Any advice please? Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've faced the same issue and it turned out that the cause of the issue is the fabric gradle plugin (crashlytics) rather than gradle itself.

Basically, the issue occurs when setting `ext.enableCrashlytics = true` in your `build.gradle` file using `io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.31.2` fabric plugin.

### Workaround

You have to avoid explicitly setting `ext.enableCrashlytics` to `true` (`false` is okay).

For example, you can replace the following code

```
def enableCrashlytics = // comes from somewhere
ext.enableCrashlytics = enableCrashlytics
```

by

```
def enableCrashlytics = // comes from somewhere
if (!enableCrashlytics) {
    ext.enableCrashlytics = false
}
```

The behavior remains the same since crashlytics is enabled by default.

As an alternative, you can revert to using `1.31.0` which works fine, but I'd not recommend doing it since the latest version contains a couple of critical [bug fixes](https://docs.fabric.io/android/changelog.html#fabric-gradle-plugin).

Also, you can consider migrating to Firebase Crashlytics (currently in beta) since Google is [dropping support](https://docs.fabric.io/android/examples/firebase/fabric-shutdown.html) for Fabric soon and this issue might not get fixed.

Answer (score 15):

Remove `apply plugin: 'io.fabric'` help me, but how return crashlytics...

Answer (score 5):

Fabric is deprecated use Firebase instead. Refer to this page on how to migrate
https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=android